# Maven setup on Windows: ';' expected

Tags: maven

When running command

```
mvn package
```

I get the following error: 
/C:/Windows/System32/playground-project/src/main/java/com/my-organization/App.java:[1,15] ';' expected

Now for the App.java, it looks like this:

```
package com.my-organization;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

Some suggestions?

Comment: I don't think `-` is allowed in package names, try `package com.myCompany;`

Answer (score 1):

The `-` character is not allowed in package names.
make it `myorganization`, rename the folder, and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I renamed it and ran the command again but now it gave another error : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project playground-project: Error while storing the mojo status: C:\Windows\System32\playground-project\target\maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin\compile\default-compile\createdFiles.lst (Access is denied)

Comment: your project should probably live on your desktop or documents folder, not in windows\system32, which is a system folder that windows has security restrictions on...